# Is it best practice to assign a std::vector<T> to a variable before iteration?

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector

I'm working with a smart pointer which returns a `std::vector<T>` over which I want to iterate using a `for` loop.

Are there any disadvantages to returning the `std::vector<T>` directly within the `for` loop as opposed to assigning it to a variable before the loop?

For example, instead of this:

```cpp
const myClass& vec = myPtr->getVec();
for (const itemPtr& item : vec)
{
    ...
}
```

Can I safely do this?:

```cpp
for (const itemPtr& item : myPtr->getVec())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do that without any problems.

Comment: For this use-case it doesn't really matter. The bigger problem in my mind is what `getVec()` returns? Will it return a reference or a copy? I would also argue that using a class like only a container for member variables is usually not a good design. If you need to do some operation on all elements of an internal vector, then possibly create a function which takes a callable object and does the iteration itself inside the object. I'm also a little bit worried about the need for a pointer in your code, those are seldom needed, unless you deal with polymorphism.

Comment: If you use C++23 and beyond, you can write practically any range-expression you want with no worries. The language will extend the lifetime of any temporaries that pop up there for the loop duration, without gotchas.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you; here, `getVec()` would return a reference.

Comment: One advantage with the first snippet is for debugging, you have a variable to inspect the whole vector (especially true if `getVec()` is not a simple getter).

Comment: _`getVec()` would return a reference_ - a reference to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, a binding to a reference is part of declared range for-loop functionality, only it uses an rvalue reference (result could have been a temporary):

```
//for ( init-statement (optional) range-declaration : range-expression )
//   loop-statement

{
  init-statement
  auto && __range = range-expression ;
  auto __begin = begin-expr ;
  auto __end = end-expr ;
  for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
  {
    range-declaration = *__begin;
    loop-statement
  }
}
```

Comment: `auto&&` is a forwarding reference, not an rvalue reference.